# My Project and Admin panel's resource can not be retrieve, but Identity resource can be retrieve, after I use the openstacksdk change the password

Tags: openstack

My Project and Admin panel's resource can not be retrieve, but Identity resource can be retrieve, after I use the openstacksdk change the password:

```
conn.identity.update_user(user_id, password=new_password)  # after this step, the Project and Admin resources can not be retrieved.
```

Now my Project and Admin's resources can not be retrieved:

[image]

But the Identity resources can retrieve:

[image]

And please attention, when I login the openstack dashboard, I still use the old_password, can not use the new_password login the openstack dashboard.

And, if I use the `conn.identity.update_user` method change to the old_password, then the issue will gone, there will become normal.

---

**EDIT -1**

I use the command :

`openstack role assignment list --names`

to check the role assignment list:

`[root@controller ~]# openstack role assignment list --names
+-------+-------------------+-------+-----------------+--------+-----------+
| Role  | User              | Group | Project         | Domain | Inherited |
+-------+-------------------+-------+-----------------+--------+-----------+
| user  | demo@Default      |       | demo@Default    |        | False     |
| admin | nova@Default      |       | service@Default |        | False     |
| admin | cinder@Default    |       | service@Default |        | False     |
| admin | glance@Default    |       | service@Default |        | False     |
| admin | placement@Default |       | service@Default |        | False     |
| admin | neutron@Default   |       | service@Default |        | False     |
| admin | admin@Default     |       | admin@Default   |        | False     |
+-------+-------------------+-------+-----------------+--------+-----------+`

Answer (score 0):

This *sounds* like a roles issue.  I would use one of the OpenStack CLI to check out the roles:

```
openstack role assignment list --names
```

Something like that assuming a recent version of OpenStack.  I don't know enough about Horizon to know what roles are needed to view those pages.